# When the action in a noun clause happens in the future, which tense should I use in the noun clause?

Tags: grammar, tense, clauses

When the action in a noun clause happens in the future, which tense should I use in the noun clause?

Are the tenses different in meaning if they are all grammatically correct when used in the clause? If yes, shed light on it, thanks a lot!

Here are two examples explaining my questions.

Example 1:

> > (The son is going to have a adventure to somewhere far away.)
> >
> > Father talking to the son: Hey, son, when you come back, tell me what you **see / saw / will see / will have seen** in the journey.

Example 2:

> > (I am about to go study overseas.)
> >
> > I talking to mom: Mom, when I come home, I will share with you what I **learn / learned / will learn / will have learned** overseas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple past:

> Hey, son, when you come back, tell me what you **saw**.
>
> Mom, when I come home, I will share with you what I **learned**.

The reasoning is that the object of the main clause is already stated to be in the future by the "when ..." clause. Therefore in the context of the object clause, the events will have happened in the past.

Also, "**on** the journey" is more idiomatic than "in."

Comment: Why not will have seen because the action has not begun  at the time of speaking

Comment: @user5577 that's just not how English tenses work in this case. The object clause containing this verb is "set" in the future and in that future what you saw/learned has already happened. I'm afraid I can't give a better explanation myself - I realize other languages work differently!

Comment: @user5577: The "explanation" as to why we use a "past" tense in the cited is because *at the projected future time,* what the son will be telling / sharing will be ***in the past, from his point of view at that future time***. But note that it would also be fine to use a Perfect form *(what you **have seen**, what I **have** learned).* And perhaps that could be seen as a "better" tense choice, because it implies a contextually relevant strong relationship between the past seeing / learning and the ***chronologically more recent*** "present in the future" time when the son conveys his info.

Comment: (Native speakers normally avoid convoluted forms like ***what I will have seen***. But that doesn't mean they're syntactically invalid; we just don't use them much.)

Comment: [Obligatory Douglas Adams excerpt involving convoluted tenses when time traveling](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/369785-one-of-the-major-problems-encountered-in-time-travel-is). Note, **these tenses are fictional**, not real English tenses: this excerpt is meant as humor.